# Conditional form actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm not sure if I just have a solution design issue, but I have an MVC form in an Umbraco project. Umbraco has its own helper extension for forms called `BeginUmbracoForm`.  The form submissions are saved into a regular SQL database outside of Umbraco, so I have a normal MVC project to administer the form submissions (admin's can approve, decline and edit the submissions).

The problem I have is that I'm reusing the Umbraco form within the admin section.  It didn't make any sense to create a duplicate form with the exact same fields just for editing.

However, I can't use `BeginUmbracoForm` in the admin project since it's a normal MVC project.  Also I can't post to the same `Controller` since Umbraco Controllers requires inheriting from `SurfaceController`.

So basically, I need something like:

```
if (@Model.IsAdmin)
{
    @using ( Html.BeginForm<AdminController>("EditForm") )
}
else
{
    @using ( Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbracoController>("SubmitForm") )
}
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, and I'm thinking I might need to create the admin section within Umbraco.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an admin section within the Umbraco application is a security decision which your domain administrator should make. There is a good case to separate your code base into separate web projects rather than share a single code base.

You would ideally encapsulate your business logic into the domain they serve rather than introduce strict coupling between them. That way your websites could exist in isolation. Be deployed to different end points. Use different technologies and security principals to serve their business function.

[**Wikipedia**: Domain-driven design (Bounded context)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Bounded_context)

It may seem like an over-engineered solution to a simple problem but I'm sure every developer can recount a project which started out with a few hacks that quickly escalated into a *big-ball-of-mud* application.